# What image best defines an upcoming event?

Tags: mobile, intuition, empty-state

I'm building an app for football players. After each match, there is a match stats card where the results will available 24h after the match. I'm not sure if I should go simple or more illustrative. Which one of the 4 would you say best define thisempty state at first glance?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most illustrative, direct, recognizable, and easy-to-understand element for any user for an event to occur on a given date/hour/minute is a countdown.

[image: Countdown]

<sub>*Image source [dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/13844344-Daily-UI-014-Countdown-Timer)*</sub>

Comment: This is actually a great idea that I didn't think about

Answer (score 0):

We could suggest the following methods

1. Create a simple message stating that the data will be availble on a specifc time or date(or even a relative time). The title of the message should be more of a postive tone indicating the data will be available soon.
2. Adding an illustration is fine, but not over complicating the application size. Also the illustration must be of the similar style which you are using on other similar areas.

Overall if you ask me, I would choose the **option C** from the above versions.

Comment: I'm using detailed illustrations (like the D version) on empty states for entire pages as opposed to empty content inside of cards. So, I think having two types of illustrations (one more complex and other simpler) is ok as long as the are consistent depending on the context in which they are being used for.

Comment: Yes. That would be fine @dreds10