# Best UX for blocking users from using a form twice

Tags: forms, error-message, applications

I'm designing ***an application experience*** and looking for the best UX practices.
Here's the **scenario**:

1. User submits the form and gets their results immediately on the next screen + emailed to them. Results do not change for 1 month, users are informed of that.
2. In a week, the same user is back using the form. They either forgot that they submitted it earlier or are trying to "cheat the system" and get a different result. When they submit, they get the same results they saw the first time they submitted.

The application is made up of **three parts**: Landing page, Form, and Results page.

**My question:** at what point do I remind the user that they have used this tool recently and results will not change for a full month from the first application?

- do I block the user from submitting the form.
- do I display a reminder message on the results page saying something along the lines of "you submitted earlier, try again on x date for different results".
- do nothing and just display the same results as the first time.
- Give users a retrieve button on the landing page where they can add their email.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you *want* your users to try again each month? Or is it more like if they come back after a month, they can try again, but you don't really want to advertise that?

Comment: the second case, not really advertising it, it's just open for them to try again.

Answer (score 2):

If the user has already filled out the form, visiting the site a second time doesn't require them to view the form again. A message on the main page thanking them very much for the new visit would suffice with a "very small bottom text" clarifying the reasons why the form is not active/visible at that moment and probably a [countdown](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/142708/115107).

With this simple action, you avoid: blocking the user, something with always negative results towards the site, displaying a reminder message with explanations, or adding an extra function to the page.

In any case, a viewer of the delivered form or/and a download button in any visible file format

Comment: This. But I think you could also show the data for the already submitted form in case it's necessary to remind the user

Comment: The count-down?

Comment: No, I mean whichever data the user submitted at first, only that instead of a form, just showing the plain data. Like "On July 11, 2022 you submitted this......., please wait until August 11 to resubmit". Just an idea

Answer (score 1):

Be friendly and let the user know that they're done, and what they can do next, without placing blame. If they came back in error, they're receiving a friendly reminder.

[image: Empty state with graphic, your application was received message, instructions on what to do.]

If they're trying to game the system, they're still not able to proceed, and you're still being polite. If you want to be really nice, you could add a "Remind me" link and send them an email (or a calendar invitation) on the date the job opens to them again, but you've stated that it's not important to help the user try again. A reminder might prompt them to apply for a job that's a better fit at your company, or share with a friend - just some things to consider.

You can also use a dashboard to help applicants keep track of their statuses, like Submittable does here, which can cut down on people applying in error.

[image: Submittable dashboard]